# Word JS API. body.paragraphs collection is not updated when paragraphs were added or deleted in the runtime

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am experimenting with API in Scriptlab and encountered with a problem. My script inserts some paragraphs in the document and then i want to cycle through all the paragraphs in the document and change some formatting. But it seems that `body.paragraphs` collection is not updating between `context.sync()` calls.

Here is the sample code:

```
async function run() {
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    var pars = context.document.body.paragraphs.load("items");
    await context.sync();
    // Returns "1", as the document has only one empty paragraph
    console.log(pars.items.length);
    // Insert three new paragraphs. Now there are 4 in the document
    ["Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"].forEach(p => context.document.body.insertParagraph(p,"End"));
    
    pars = context.document.body.paragraphs.load("items");
    await context.sync();
    //But I still get 1 in the console window!
    console.log(pars.items.length);
    //New paragraphs are unchanged when we iterate over them
    pars.items.forEach(p => p.set({lineSpacing: 40, leftIndent: 10 }))
    await context.sync();
  })
}
```

This behavior is experienced in Word Online

How can I get the updated paragraph collection?

Comment: Do the new paragraphs appear in the document?

Comment: Yes, they do. The text inside them is discoverable via `body.search()` method. Also references to them could be saved and manipulated within one `Word.run()`

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Your code works fine for me. I can't put a screenshot in a comment, but I get a "1" and below that a "4" in the ScriptLab console. Maybe you could try uninstalling ScriptLab and reinstalling it.

Comment: @RickKirkham Thank you for testing. It seems to be a bug in Word Online, as the code works well with desktop app. I have reported feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Hi Your code is not correct. "pars" should be paragraphcollection.Could you please try this code:

```
const body = context.document.body;
body.clear();
["Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"].forEach(p => body.insertParagraph(p, "End"));

var pars = context.document.body.paragraphs;
pars.load();
await context.sync();
console.log(pars.items.length);
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! I've tried, but this doesn't work either (for some reason). BTW assigning object to a variable and loading properties at the same time is not an error. Michael Zlatkovsky wrote in his book _Building Office Add-ins_ mentions that `...the return value of object.load(...) is the object itself. This is done purely for convenience, saving a line or two of vertical space.` (Page 51, available in free excerpt at [link](https://leanpub.com/buildingofficeaddins))

Comment: I have tested it in the scriptlab. It works for me.